# Does Windows 11 always come with English language choice in OOBE?

Tags: windows-11, language

The title of the question asks it all. Will you always be able to select English as language when walking through the Out of Box Experience in Windows 11. No matter what the language is in the region you purchase the PC.

Here is why. A customer of mine is in Thailand. He needs to purchase a new laptop. He is not technically savvy. He needs to run through the OOBE and then I can support him using a remote assistance program.

He told me "all PCs here are in Thai language". Which is obviously so for all models on display. But if he purchases a laptop, would he be able to install it in English.

It is no use if the only option is to install in Thai and try to add an English language pack later. He would not even be able to download a remote support program. And changing a language on Windows usually works for 95% anyway. Then there is the danger that the Windows license is a "single language license".

It really must be possible during initial Out of Box Experience.

Comment: No matter what the language is in the region you purchase the PC.   .....  I am pretty sure it matters where you purchased the PC to get it to start in the language you want.

Comment: “No matter what the language is in the region you purchase the PC.” - Yes; Unless it’s Single Language

Comment: @John. IDK. I have had PCs intended for the German, UK and South American market. They all had English as a choice during OOBE. But in those countries it is not uncommon to install a PC in en-US. About Asia I am not sure.

Comment: I think it depends on where sold, who (manufacturer) loads it, and what languages are loaded.

Comment: I believe that the  OOBE can be tailored by the vendor, so perhaps the question should be directed to them.

Comment: @john harrymc  It makes sense what you say. I had not realized that there is the manufacturer between Microsoft and the customer. Then this question cannot be answered by this forum. I advised my customer Asus or HP. But that still does not tell anything about the policy they have in Thailand.